# Difference in the implied meaning when different words for "cheating" used?

Tags: meaning, differences

Please consider the sentences below:

> He **chiseled** me out of my dues.
>   He **swindled** me out of dues.
>   He **cheated** me out of my dues.

Below are the definitions given by Dictionary

> **Chisel** = cheat or swindle (someone) out of something.
>   **Swindle** = use deception to deprive (someone) of money or possessions.

I learn that any of the two words in any language doesn't implies same meanings all the time. What is the difference in the meaning if I use above three words individually in the given sentence?

Comment: There is a significant difference if your wife is the malefactor.

Answer (score 7):

*Chisel* is colloquial, and rather old-fashioned now; its use peaked about 1940 and has been declining since.

*Swindle* may be used either colloquially or formally, and bears a suggestion of illegality. (But in actual law the term is usually *defraud*).

*Cheat* is the most "generic" of the three terms; it is used not only of fraudulently or underhandedly depriving someone of material assets but also in figurative senses: "cheating death", for instance, or "cheating an audience's expectations" (or "cheating an audience of its expectations").

Comment: Those are exactly the same distinctions I would make. Chief among them being that anyone interested in learning and using *current* English should probably forget about using *chisel* in this sense. NGrams [supports my gut feeling](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chiseled+me+out+of%2Ccheated+me+out+of%2Cswindled+me+out+of&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=) that *swindling [someone out of something]* is also falling out of fashion, leaving *cheating* as probably the best choice today.

Answer (score 0):

In English, many words can be used in a variety of contexts. In this instance, the three words will give the sentence the same meaning.

'swindle' does give a possible interpretation of being fooled or being a bit gullible, but they all have the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Two different words would never have the same meaning. In other words, different words convey different concepts. While using words, some considerations such as what, where, when as well as how to whom the vocabulary is used must be taken into account.